# Detect code that changes attribute value in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging

I inherited a huge Rails application from previous developer and now encounter a bug - an attribute gets changed suddenly in an incorrect way by some code.

I am looking for some tools that will help me to detect code that makes an incorrect change. The attribute is being updated in many places across the app.

Comment: Lots of `puts` / `logger.info` statements in the code is probably the only way :-)

Comment: @Prakash Murthy: Oh, god! There is already a lot of logging. It is very hard to find something in these logs.

Comment: Inspired by The RSpec book, I use `logger.info "\n###\nSomething to log from somewhere\n###\n"` to get the log to show up distinctively.

Comment: I don't know the whole case but it looks like setting up logging is like the debugging an application step by step. I mean if you know on which action that happens (or which actions) you can debug the property's value. I would do it right into console with the simple puts. Maybe it would help if you switched off one by one before filters and looked if something changed.

Comment: http://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2014-01-14-debugging-super-methods-ruby22?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email

Comment: Is it happening on a schedule?  I encountered a similar situation once, it turns out a cron job was hitting something, and the data it was using did not include a value that had been added, so it was overwriting stuff.  Best of luck getting it solved!

Answer (score 2):

The master [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) has a recommendation on debugging.  The tool they recommend is called [ByeBug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug).  You include the gem 'byebug', and you put the method **byebug** where you believe the change is occurring and you can step through your code one line at a time while it's occurring and check the local variables as you go along.

Answer (score 1):

Without being affiliated with the product, I am using RubyMine, you have a debbuging modus that helped me quite a bit in the past:

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

Here is some more information on debugging rails applications:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Here my gem essentials for development environemnts on rails:

```
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.1.0'
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.14.0"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.2.1"
  gem 'seed_dump'
end
```

Take a look at better errors - it usually does the job (perhaps not for this particular issue you are facing but in general you figure out 98% of errors without skimming the rails server output).
- https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors

Comment: The problem is that this very specific change occurs very rare and in production only. It could not be reproduced in development.

Comment: Paul, I can hardly help you without knowing what the exact issue is. Have you mirrored the production DB and pulled the latest source on your dev? I suppose you do not know the steps to reproduce this issue? Any hints you can post here ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any unique answer to this.

I think the main point is to identify where the replacement data might be generated and then try to narrow down where this data might be used using logging as some other suggested.

Optionally read below.

I just had such issue with oracle-enhanced adapter project. I tried to add some features and tests and it turned out something is modifying attributes on save which broke my unrelated tests. It costed me a good few hours to identify.

It happened with the `raw` field type so that narrowed down the issue somehow. I saw that `#serialize` method modified the original data into the wrong one.

Then I tried to identify where that data might have been used. Not too hard to guess it should have been used within the backtrace of whatever was calling `#serialize`. But it is so obfuscated with all these callbacks that I thought I can use a shortcut and see if I more easily identify the spot by debugging on `#deserialize` although no custom `#deserialize` existed.

Looking at backtrace with the debugger I figured out that `ActiveModel::ActiveModel#forget_attribute_assignments` has been called during `#save`, which in turn used `#deserialize` on the just serialized data.

The funny thing is that data coming from database does not need deserialization. So IMO it is an inefficiency of current ActiveRecord version to do extra deserialization. Now working around this is a separate topic.

The above is not directly applicable to you because you said you see it only in production so you can't use a debugger.

The main point though is IMO to identify where the replacement data might be generated and then try to narrow down where this data might be used.